# How to update Entity Framework from DataSet that is reading XML?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, entity-framework

I want to update my database over a WCF Data Service and the Entity Framework
from an XML file read from disk. 
I am using a DataSet to read the XML file but I don't know how to update the database from the dataset via the Entity Framework part.
I am using a DataSet to read the XML because it works so well but if there
is another way to read XML into the database via Entity Framework that would be great.
The code I want looks like the following.

```
private void AddToDBFromXMLFile(string xmlFile)
{
    // this is reading my XML just fine, but i suspect there is another way to 
    // get the XML into the
    // database,  otherwise how can I get the XML into the database via the EF?
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFile, XmlReadMode.InferSchema);

    // this is working and can update and retrieve my data using the usual methods
    var proxy = new TestApp.ServiceReference.TestEntities(new
    Uri("http://localhost:4976/TestWcfDataService.svc/"));


    // how do I update the database from the dataset?
    //proxy  << dataset 
}
```